# Updated to Chrome v65 and started getting this error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, onclick, minify

I have a React app that recently starting emitting this error.

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=94&args[]=onClick&args[]=string

```
Minified React error #94:

Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string
```

When this error appears, none of our buttons/dropdowns work but the webpage isn't frozen. It only happens in one section of the app. When we navigate to another section and come back, the error does NOT appear again.

I've gone over every single `onClick` event in our app and there's not a single function that could possibly be passed in as a string or can be returned as a string. Although we have a few `onClick` events that can be passed a `NULL` object.

But we've narrowed down the steps that produced this bug:

1. It only started occurring when we updated to **Chrome version 65**, which only came out 2 days ago. The bug does NOT happen in previous Chrome versions (before v65)
2. It only happens in our production build of the React app, not on `localhost` (could it be a minifying error?)
3. The bug doesn't happen in our other apps, also built with React and minified with similar webpack configurations.

Does anyone have an idea of why this error is happening and how we can solve it?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error message in Chrome console]

Comment: do other browsers work?

Comment: We didn't bother testing for other browsers because our app is internal and the users can only use Chrome. I will try and see if anything pops up anyway :)

Comment: Of course, if your code is meant to only run in Chrome, there could be a lot more Chrome-specific stuff you use that will break other browsers - but it would be interesting to test anyway

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue in my application right after login. That page throws React error 94 like yours in prod, but nothing gets thrown locally. This is completely breaking our QA automation since it relies on a Docker container with the latest Chrome to run Selenium tests. Another note: Chrome Canary (v67) seems to run everything without error.

Comment: @PP_vinnieg it seems like the common denominator is minified React code being incompatible with Chrome v65... some libraries will produce this bug. I think the 2 solutions are: 1) Find the problematic component/function and try re-writing it somehow or using a different component library temporarily or 2) use un-minified React code in your production env temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it's specifically the minified/production build of React that's incompatible with Chrome65.

We flipped process.env.NODE_ENV back to 'development', until we find a better solution, or Chrome resolves the issue with v65.

---

Update: If you are using the `toJS()` HOC from redux (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.md#use-a-higher-order-component-to-convert-your-smart-components-immutablejs-props-to-your-dumb-components-javascript-props), the problem is with `Object.entries()`.

To fix this for now, replace `Object.entries` with a custom `entries` function:

(ES6)

`const entries = x => Object.keys(x).reduce((y, z) => y.push([z, x[z]]) && y, []);`

You should be able to flip your NODE_ENV back to 'production'.

Currently trying to figure out why the `wrappedComponentProps` object causes the issue, but a regular object like `{ myFunc: function(){} }` doesn't.

(Any help debugging this would be appreciated!)

Calling `delete wrapperComponentProps[ANY-VALID-KEY]` before running `Object.entries()` fixes the issue, so I suspect it's something to do with object security/caching.

Comment: Ah we don't have this specific error nor do we use `toJS` but kudos to logging this bug and posting a solution. We also considered running an un-minified build of React in production until the bug gets solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I still think there was an error with Chrome v 65's minification process but I started deleting clickable components from my app until the error was gone to flush out the problematic component.

Turns out it was a `<LinkContainer />` from `react-bootstrap-router` library that was causing the bug. We replaced with `react-router` link components and the error went away!